# ImageMagick png to svg Image Size

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have successfully converted a PNG to an SVG using the following command:

```
convert Slide3.png Slide3_converted.svg
```

The problem is the resulting file is a whopping 380MB!

I tried this version of the command:

```
convert -size 2000x1200 Slide3.png Slide3_converted_smaller.svg
```

But no dice. Same size.

Comment: you forgot to write png file size. Png to svg is not easy task, can you use other converters? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_to_vector http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SVG is a vector image format, so converting a raster image (jpg, png, gif etc.) to svg can be a complex task.

I tried to convert a simple image: white background with a red circle and a blue square using:

```
convert input.png output.svg
```

here's a sample from the svg file created by this command:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="800" height="600">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="1" cy="0" r="1" fill="white"/>
  ...
  <circle cx="218" cy="151" r="1" fill="rgb(255,247,247)"/>
  <circle cx="219" cy="151" r="1" fill="rgb(255,40,40)"/>
  <circle cx="220" cy="151" r="1" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="221" cy="151" r="1" fill="rgb(255,127,127)"/>
  <circle cx="222" cy="151" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="223" cy="151" r="1" fill="white"/>
  ...
  <circle cx="799" cy="599" r="1" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

basically ImageMagick created a 1px radius circle for each pixel, painting it in the correct color.
Starting from a 5KB png my output was a 22MB svg, this explains the huge file size you obtained.

According to ImageMagick documentation (see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg_output)) this happens because "**AutoTrace**" (see [here](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/)) library is missing:

> "If the "AutoTrace" library is not installed and compiled into IM,
>   then the **SVG output generated will be a huge number of single pixel
>   circles**, generating a binary result, **rather than a smooth SVG outlined
>   image**. Such images are huge by comparision, and often take a very long
>   time to render by by SVG render."

once you have installed AutoTrace library you can try with something like this:

```
convert autotrace:A.gif  A_traced.png
```